# text on arrow for xypic

Tags: xy-pic

In the following example, I find that the `u` and `w` are vertically too far from the arrow: is there any way so that

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{E \ar[r]^-*+{u}
        \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v} &E \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v}\\
                  E/F \ar@{.>}[r]^-*+{w}& E/F}


\end{document}
```

thanks for your answer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing replacing, for example,

```
^-*+{u}
```

with (adjust `1pt` to your needs):

```
^*-<1pt>{u}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{E \ar[r]^*-<1pt>{u}
        \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v} &E \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v}\\
                  E/F \ar@{.>}[r]^*-<1pt>{w}& E/F}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that you can set a global value for all arrows by adding `@L=dimen` after `\xymatrix`.

For example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@L=-.5pt{E \ar[r]^-*+{u}
        \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v} &E \ar@{->>}[d]^-*+{v}\\
                  E/F \ar@{.>}[r]^-*+{w}& E/F}


\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @VincentBeck Happy about that. Remember that you can accept the answer, if you want. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)